# UserActions logic is moved to @spartacus/user

Tags: spartacus-storefront

Based on this upgrade suggestion I’m trying to import UserActions/UserDetailsAction from @spartacus/user lib but am getting the error has no exported member.
// TODO:Spartacus - UserActions - Following actions 'ForgotPasswordEmailRequestAction', 'ResetPasswordAction', 'EmailActions', 'UpdatePasswordAction', 'UserDetailsAction' were removed. Logic was moved to '@spartacus/user'

Module ‘“@spartacus/user”’ has no exported member ‘UserActions’.

`import {  UserActions } from '@spartacus/user';`
`this.store.dispatch(new UserActions.LoadUserDetails(user));`

`import {  UserActions } from '@spartacus/user';`

Tried to import UserActions from the user lib

Comment: May I ask you to provide which version of Spartacus you currently use and which was used before the upgrade? Thanks!

Comment: Hi @PawełFraś, thanks for your response. We're trying to upgrade from v3 to v4.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [technical changes documentation](https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/technical-changes-version-4/#ngrx-state-of-the-user-feature), you should use the new recommended approach with commands and queries as mentioned in the link. But you can also try importing from `@spartacus/user/account`, `@spartacus/user/profile` or `@spartacus/core` bearing in mind that your previously used actions may not exist anymore.

In case it helps, a similar question was also asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70864124/how-to-migrate-legacy-actions-in-spartacus-sap).

Answer (score 1):

Based on [technical changes in Spartacus 4.0](https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/blob/4.3.8/docs/migration/4_0.md#ngrx-state-of-the-user-feature), Some branches of the ngrx state for the User feature were removed and logic has been moved to facades in `@spartacus/user` library.

In your case, instead of dispatching an action, simply use the `get` method from `UserAccountFacade` that is part of `@spartacus/user`.